# How to list blog posts of a particular user in Django REST Api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

How to list blog posts of a particular user.

using ListAPIView, all blog posts are listed. How to list blog posts of a particular user?

**views.py**

```
class BlogList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = models.Blog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.BlogSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'user_id', 'title', 'content', 'created_at',)
        model = models.Blog
```

**urls.py**

```
path('', views.BlogList.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which user? current user? Or any other user?

If any user, current or otherwise, then you can do this:

```
class BlogList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.BlogSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Blog.objects.filter(user_id=self.kwargs['user_id'])
```

And in the urlconf or urls.py:

```
# Make sure you are passing the user id in the url.
# Otherwise the list view will not pick it up.
path('<int:user_id>', views.BlogList.as_view()),
```

So a url like this: 'app_name/user_id/' should give you a list of all of the blogs belonging to the user with user_id.

Also, you can learn a lot more by visiting the page provided by luizbag.

Answer (score -2):

You need to make a query using user as filter.

On your BlogList class:

```
class BlogList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = models.Blog.objects.filter(user_id = self.request.user.id)
    serializer_class = serializers.BlogSerializer
```

Check this link for reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-current-user